# How to use Windows Server 2012 and 2008 on AWS EC2 instance in free tier

Tags: amazon-s3

How to use Windows Server 2012 and 2008 as an AWS instanace in free tier account? I am having free tier account on AWS, so can I use Windows Server as my instance?

Answer (score 0):

From [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/):

> **AWS Free Tier (Per Month):**
>
> **Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2)**
>
> - 750 hours of Amazon EC2 Linux **t2.micro instance** usage (1 GiB of memory and 32-bit and 64-bit platform support) – enough hours to run continuously each month
> - 750 hours of Amazon EC2 Microsoft Windows Server **t2.micro** instance usage (1 GiB of memory and 32-bit and 64-bit platform support) – enough hours to run continuously each month

Note that the restriction is on the **instance type** -- it needs to be a `t2.micro` instance (but possibly also includes the older `t1.micro`).

When launching an Amazon EC2 instance, select an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) that says "**Free tier eligible**". This currently includes:

- Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Base
- Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Base
- Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Base

[image]

Comment: so this means i can use r8?

Comment: No. You can only use t2.micro (and possibly t1.micro) for free, for up to 750 hours per month. The "account" isn't free tier. Rather, certain services fall into a free tier -- in the case of EC2, the rules are as above. See http://aws.amazon.com/free

Comment: But as you posted windows free tier snapshot, it is clearly showing free tier...is it not free?

Comment: And does amazon will charge me after 1 year?

Comment: Please refer to http://aws.amazon.com/free for full details of what is included in the Free Usage Tier.